# generating a data that has a specific R-square

Tags: python, regression, data-generation

for a regression, how can I generate series of data that has a specific R-square with other data?
for example y has 130 record:

```
y=[0.2 , -0.056 , 0.14 ,...,-0.86]
```

how can I generate x that has 130 records and R-square(x,y) is around 0.3?

Comment: `x = y` has 130 records and rsquare 1, i.e. more than 0.3

Comment: tnx but I want the data to look random or at least don't have an obvious relationship like x=y

Comment: There's an infinite number of solutions to this. You can just copy y and add a scaled random vector to it, with an amplitude just large enough to give you the rsquared you want.

Comment: tnx for your answer
it worked